# How to remove characters within a date in R

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I have a dataframe with a "Date" column, several thousand rows long. The dates are within their own cell, in this format:

```
2006-06-24
```

How can I get my "Date" column down to just the year, and then apply it to the rest of the rows? The dates change, and go through 2018. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with sub and a regular expression.

```
Date = c("2006-06-24", "2007-07-25", "2008-08-26")
sub("(\\d{4})-.*", "\\1", Date)
[1] "2006" "2007" "2008"
```

Answer (score 2):

If data is already in `Date/POSIXct` format then you can use `format` as:

```
# Sample data
v <- as.Date(c("2006-06-24","2006-06-25","2006-06-26"))

format(v,"%Y")
#[1] "2006" "2006" "2006"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged `dplyr`, here's a tidyverse solution using `lubridate::year()`:

```
library(lubridate)

dates <- c("2006-06-24", "2007-06-24")
year(dates)

[1] 2006 2007
```